# Navigate between fragments (ViewFlipper)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) with a ViewFlipper and within this I have several fragments

### `src/com.package.WelcomeActivity.java`

```
package com.package;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class WelcomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

### `res/layout/activity_welcome.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewFlipper 
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/flip2"
            class="com.package.fragment2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/flip2"
            class="com.package.fragment2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <!-- ... -->
        <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/flipN"
            class="com.package.fragmentN"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now each fragment are composed by two mayor parts: content and actions (back, continue) when the user tab on continue action execute a function inside the fragment but i dont know how to call the `ViewFlipper.showNext()` and `ViewFlipper.showPrevious()` inside the fragments

Comment: Post you entire code for the activity ? I mean FrgmentActivity :)

Comment: Fragments add them via XML for this reason I can not pass the ViewFlipper and I don't want to do it this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your Activity do it.

Make public methods in your `WelcomeActivity` that call `ViewFlipper.showNext()` and `ViewFlipper.showPrevious`, something like this:

```
public void showNextFragment() {
    mViewFlipper.showNext();
}

public void showPreviousFragment() {
    mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
}
```

In your fragments, you can then call the Activity's methods, like this:

```
WelcomeActivity parent = (WelcomeActivity) getActivity();
parent.showNextFragment();
// or parent.showPreviousFragment();
```

I just typed the code here and didn't try it, there might be typo, so don't just copy-paste. But I hope it's illustrating my point well.